# Add custom field inside a do_shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, contact-form-7

I'm trying to add a contact form into a page template with contact form 7. However, I want the destination email to come in from a custom field I have created.

The code that pulls the custom field data in is this:

```
<?php the_field('website_address'); ?>
```

The shortcode which lets me select the destination email at template level is:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email="xxxxxx@example.com"]'); ?>
```

So I need to add the website_address into the shortcode. I've tried the following:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email="<?php the_field('website_address'); ?>"]'); ?>
```

But it has a PHP tag inside a PHP tag so it doesn't work...

So I tried these:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email="the_field('website_address')"]'); ?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email="get_field('website_address')"]'); ?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email=".get_field('website_address')."]'); ?>

<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email="'.get_field('website_address').'"]'); ?>
```

None of which are working correctly, some even break the page.

I'm struggling to find answer so was wondering if someone could enlighten me - I might even be thinking of it all in the wrong way! Thanks a lot for looking :)

EDIT

There's a function I need to include which I have added to functions.php but it still isn't helping...

```
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_wpcf7', 'custom_shortcode_atts_wpcf7_filter', 10, 3 );

function custom_shortcode_atts_wpcf7_filter( $out, $pairs, $atts ) {
  $my_attr = 'destination-email';

  if ( isset( $atts[$my_attr] ) ) {
    $out[$my_attr] = $atts[$my_attr];
  }

  return $out;
}
```

It's from the page: https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-shortcode-attributes/

Comment: Have you tried <?php $addr = get_field('website_address');  echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email="'.$addr.'"]'); ?>

Comment: Technically, your last one should have worked also.

Comment: Thanks so much... Ive just realised there's a function to go with it that im missing to ensure the custom shortcode works... I've added it to the bottom of my original question above... Im not sure if it conflicts with anything...

Comment: The problem is that even if you pass your own attribute, Contact Form 7 won't know what to do with it unless you add that field to your form. Do you have a `destination-email` field?

Comment: `get_field('website_address')` is this a constant, or specific to each page that your form appears on?  Can you explain how this will be returned?

Comment: HI, thanks for the responses - I think I might have the wrong end of the stick a little with that contact form 7 link... Its a membership website essentially, members are CPTs and I'm using ACF to display an email address on each member page. So, get_field('website_address') is different for each member... Im essentially trying o add a contact form on each member page so people who browse can directly get in touch with that member... Perhaps I actually dont need it if were showing their email address anyway!! :-/

Comment: You could pass it with Ajax if you wanted to do this.

Comment: Ah thanks Howard, that’s interesting, would you know what type of thing I should be searching for to find the answer in Ajax?

Comment: Managed to get it working now - thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to do this as explained here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-emaip-recipient-from-shortcode/

1. Add the shortcode with the destination email in the page or post where you want to show the form:

   [contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email="xxxxxx@example.com"]
2. Add the following code to the theme functions.php or your custom plugin.

   add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_wpcf7', 'custom_shortcode_atts_wpcf7_filter', 10, 3 );
   function custom_shortcode_atts_wpcf7_filter( $out, $pairs, $atts ) {
       $my_attr = 'destination-email';
       if ( isset( $atts[$my_attr] ) ) {
           $out[$my_attr] = $atts[$my_attr];
       }
       return $out;

}
3. Add this code to the Form Tab:

```
[email* destination-email default:shortcode_attr]
```

//If you want this field hidden you can use this code instead:

```
[hidden destination-email default:shortcode_attr]
```

4. In cforms7 Mail Tab add the code [destination-email] in the “To” field.

If you used the hidden field it will show the “Invalid mailbox syntax” error, but in my case I can ignore it because it works.

If the To field with hidden field doesn’t work, you can add the id to the email shorcode:

```
[email* destination-email default:shortcode_attr id:hidefield]
```

And hide the field with css:

```
#hidefield {
    display: none;
}
```

Then I just used this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="123" title="Contact Form" destination-email="'.get_field('email_address').'"]'); ?>
```

to add in the email address from the custom post type :)

Thanks everyone who answered!